# Selecting certain strings in a data frame

Tags: r, string

I have a 138x50 data frame of the following type:

```
B = matrix( c("ehre","e", "eh", "ehr", "ehrr", "f", "fi", "fie", "fiee", "fiel", "seil", "s", "se", "sei", "seii", "leiht", "l", "le", "lei", "leih", 3, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow = FALSE) 
colnames(B)<-c("ana1_1", "ana2_1", "ana3_1", "ana4_1", "points")
```

I want to create a new df "A", only containing correct answers and replacing wrong answers with an empty cell/NA:

```
A = matrix( c("ehre",NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "fiel", "seil", NA, NA, NA, NA, "leiht", NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow = FALSE)
colnames(A)<-c("ana1_1", "ana2_1", "ana3_1", "ana4_1", "points")
```

1. How do I create A, not by deleting wrong but by selecting right answers? (as this would require less answers to type in).
2. How do I count the number of strings in a row (to create column 5)?

Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: You can use `read.table('yourfile.txt', header=TRUE, na.strings=c('here', 'rhee'))` to read those values as 'NA'.  For the existing dataset. `is.na(na) <- na =='here'|na=='rhee'`.  Regarding the multiple questions, it might be better if you showed a few lines of a small example data (6 rows with 5 columns) and the expected output based on that.

Comment: You can also use: `your_data_frame[your_data_frame[["your_column"]] %in% c("here", "rhee"), "your_column"] <- NA`; here's a real example:`mtcars[mtcars[["cyl"]] %in% c("4", "6"), "cyl"] <- NA; mtcars`

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the expected output is. I think I get the input, but that could be more clear with an example, too. Is `na` the name of the data.frame, such that if I did `get("na")` I would get that data.frame?

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying input output. One more question: does it matter which column the "correct" answer is found? E.g., I'm guessing that if "ehre" was provided for column 2, it shouldn't be matched? I'm sure this comment does more to indicate that I don't fully understand the context of the use, but I don't want to provide an answer that is too narrowly crafted.

Comment: Thank you very much rbatt. No, the column is not important. There is no participant who typed "ehre" in column 2 (or any other column than 1). I think that will make the solution easier to construct.

Comment: Try `B[!grepl(paste(c('ehre', 'seil', 'leiht', 'fiel', '^[0-9]+$'), collapse="|"), B)] <- NA`

Comment: Be really careful with your answer to rbatt's question above. In this (example) dataset, indeed, no one typed "ehre" in any other columns. But if you want to build a (real-life) process, what will happen if someone does that? In general, what happens if a correct answer in question X is a wrong answer for question Y?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep` to do this.  Create a `vector` of elements that you wanted to be as non-NA based on the 'ana' columns.

```
 v1 <- c('ehre', 'seil', 'leiht', 'fiel')
```

We `paste` these together with `collapse='|'` for the `pattern` argument in `grep`

```
 pat <- paste0('^(', paste(v1, collapse='|'), ')$')
```

Create an index for the 'ana' columns

```
 indx <- grepl('^ana', colnames(B))
```

I am creating a new object 'A1' which will be the modified matrix 'B' that have only the 'ana' columns.

```
 A1 <- B[,indx]
```

The output of `grepl` will be a logical vector.  We negate (`!`) it and the assign the corresponding elements of the columns in  'A1' to `NA`

```
A1[!grepl(pat, A1)] <- NA
```

To create the 'points' column (though in the example it is already created), we get a logical index of non-NA values in the 'ana' columns (`!is.na(A1)`), get the `rowSums`, and `cbind` with the original dataset.

```
cbind(A1, Points=rowSums(!is.na(A1)))
#     ana1_1 ana2_1 ana3_1 ana4_1  Points
#[1,] "ehre" NA     "seil" "leiht" "3"   
#[2,] NA     NA     NA     NA      "0"   
#[3,] NA     NA     NA     NA      "0"   
#[4,] NA     NA     NA     NA      "0"   
#[5,] NA     "fiel" NA     NA      "1"
```

It may be better to store the results in 'data.frame' as the 'Points' is a 'numeric' vector which gets transformed to 'character' by keeping it in a `matrix` (as `matrix` can have only a single `class`).

Comment: I don't understand why you'd go through the trouble of using regular expressions; your answer, @akrun, suggests that I am missing something ...

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't deal with the `"points"` column (if I understand the question), which is what I do in the last line of my answer. Assuming the you wouldn't want something like `"ehreX"` to match to `"ehre"`, you wouldn't need (or want) the regex; Other than that, our answers are similar (unless we want to start considering computational efficiency). I'm really just striving to figure out if I'm missing something.

Comment: @rbatt You are right.  I missed the part about the `points`.  It is not needed.

Comment: @rbatt Your answer is different in that you are using `apply` while I am using `grep` on the entire dataset

Comment: I only `apply` to tally the points; We both get the points column correct in the end w/o even doing this b/c the OP has provided the correct points in `B`; I'm assuming that we won't know the correct points ahead of time. I.e., running my answer gives the same output regardless of the last line in my answer, which is only there to confirm (or if necessary create) and overwrite the current points column

Comment: @rbatt Yes, for that I am indexing the `ana` columns and matching the expected output in 'A'

Comment: OK, I see, you use rowSums last. I didn't see that until just now.

Comment: @rbatt I just saw your entire post now.  I was thinking you used `apply` before the `tally` part.  Anyway, I am posting this as I posted as a comment just after the OP posted the question without much data.  It is looking different now.

Comment: It's no problem; I think we each have distinct but valid approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun!

Answer (score 2):

I start with your `B`, which also happens to contain `"points"`, but that column isn't required. I recreated it later. So I first change all non-matches to `NA`, then I count the number of non-NA in each row (ignoring the `"points"` column) to tally up the points. The `correct` object is just a vector of correct answer that you are looking for.

```
B = matrix( c("ehre","e", "eh", "ehr", "ehrr", "f", "fi", "fie", "fiee", "fiel", "seil", "s", "se", "sei", "seii", "leiht", "l", "le", "lei", "leih", 3, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=5, ncol=5, byrow = FALSE) 
colnames(B)<-c("ana1_1", "ana2_1", "ana3_1", "ana4_1", "points")



correct <- c("ehre","fiel","seil","leiht")
A <- B
A[!A%in%correct] <- NA
A[,"points"] <- apply(A[,colnames(A)!="points"], 1, function(x)sum(!is.na(x))) #tally up non-NA's to indicate points
```

This procedure results in the following output for `A`:

```
     ana1_1 ana2_1 ana3_1 ana4_1  points
[1,] "ehre" NA     "seil" "leiht" "3"   
[2,] NA     NA     NA     NA      "0"   
[3,] NA     NA     NA     NA      "0"   
[4,] NA     NA     NA     NA      "0"   
[5,] NA     "fiel" NA     NA      "1"
```

Comment: @HausladenCarina If you found an answer helpful, consider up-voting or even accepting it (but you can only accept 1 answer).